# ASP.NET MVC controller parameters for file and user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, parameters

I am trying to receive a post from my `file` route containing the following (I have censored the content):

```
File: (binary)
Cells: C1:C25
User: {"Id":"10833556063478680686586","Email":"david126@gmail.com","Name":"David “DAVID - EDITING” Aslan","FirstName":"Aslan","LastName":"David","Picture":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACb6roIanhh50Lj1uBha7q78wMR87hkbfkooqdsOXcEluffA8g=s96-c"}
dataCategories: ["School","Kindergarten"]
```

My routes looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("file")]
public IActionResult FileUpload([FromForm] FileColRequest collectionRequest)
{
    return Ok(collectionRequest);
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("manual")]
public IActionResult ManualUpload([FromBody] ManualColRequest collectionRequestt)
{
    return Ok(collectionRequestt);
}
```

These are the classes:

```
public class CollectionRequest
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public List<string> DataCategories { get; set; }
     public GoogleUser User { get; set; }
}

public class FileColRequest : CollectionRequest
{
     [NotMapped]
     public IFormFile File { get; set; }

     [DefaultValue("C2:E25")]
     public string Cells { get; set; }
}

public class ManualColRequest : CollectionRequest
{
     public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class GoogleUser
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string? FirstName { get; set; }
     public string? LastName { get; set; }
     public string? Name { get; set; }
     public string? Picture { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public double? Lat { get; set; }
     public double? Lng { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to receive dynamic on the files route and it works does connect so I know my frontend route is working.

It will also work if I remove the user from the front and backend as well. I unfortunately do want my user on the backend.

If I do send a request to the `manual` route that works with no problems.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does the User property of CollectionRequest cause problems for the file route and not for the manual route? Both routes use the same "User" but the file route has a problem of finding user im getting this returned to the client :
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-62b5821bde042e20ab58066ee653a776-886704c84eec059c-00",
    "errors": {
        "User": [
            "The User field is required."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: If i change the User to a string then the controller will accept but i dont think thats a very good way of doing it

Comment: Why am i unable to accept User as a GoogleUser in the "file" route and able to do it in the “manual route”?

Comment: Would be great if you could share how you send the request to the API.